# Traverse XML with JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, traversal, nodevalue

this is a sample part of xml example

```
<PivotSet>
    <item>
        <column name = "M">1</column>
        <column name = "F">1640</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name = "M">2</column>
        <column name = "F">5960</column>
    </item>
</PivotSet>
<PivotSet>
    <item>
        <column name = "M">1</column>
        <column name = "F">1700</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name = "M">2</column>
        <column name = "F">7000</column>
    </item>
</PivotSet>
```

It should be as the following

```
1      
1640 1700

2
5960 7000
```

Can you help me by telling me how to do this using jquery please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same way you traverse XHTML (since it's XML).
Here's an example:

```
var xml = '<PivotSet>[...]</PivotSet>';

var $xml = $(xml);
$xml.find('column').each(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uBv2L/

---

edit: your specific case:

```
var $xml = $(xml);
var out = '1\r\n';
$xml.find('column[name="M"]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text()=='1';
}).each(function(){
  out+=$(this).next().text()+' ';
});
out += '\r\n2\r\n';
$xml.find('column[name="M"]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text()=='2';
}).each(function(){
  out+=$(this).next().text()+' ';
});

alert(out);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uBv2L/1/

Comment: great solution mate :) but what if the xml contains values other than 1 and 2? and if i do not know the node value?